# Python code to copy and update excel formulas dynamically

Tags: python, excel, pandas, automation, openpyxl

Target: I am trying to split an excel file into multiple files based on some filter given within the sheet.

Problem: An issue is arising while copying the formula columns as it is not updating the row numbers inside the formula while splitting them into multiple sheets.
For Ex: In the master file, the formula is "=LEFT(B11, FIND(" ", B11,1))" for row 11, however, this becomes the first row in the new split file but the formula is still referring to row 11 which gives "#VALUE" error in the new file.
[image: master file]

[image: splitted file]

Any ideas on how to resolve this one?

I have tried achieving this using pandas and openpyxl and failed, PFB the code.

To Load the file

```
wb = load_workbook(filepath)
sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet_name = wb[sheets[0]]
master_df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_name.values, index=False)
master_df.columns = master_df.iloc[0]
master_df = master_df[1:]
print(master_df)
```

To split amd export the file

```
temp_df = master_df[master_df['Filter Column'] == filter_criteria]
sp.export_file(temp_df, output_path + "/" + <"output file name">)
```

Comment: Neither openpyxl or pandas manage or update formulas just write them as the values read. If you move/copy the data using something like XLwings then you should expect the formulas to be updated as this works withing Excel. Therefore you'd need to manage the update of formulas yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def update_formula(df: pd.DataFrame, formula_col):
    '''
    Function to update formulas for each Manager
    :param df:  DataFrame for one specific manager.
    '''
    for _col in formula_col:
        col_alpha = formula_col[_col][0]
        formula = formula_col[_col][1]
        index = 2
        for ind, row in df.iterrows():
            df.at[ind, _col] = Translator(formula, origin=col_alpha + '2').translate_formula(col_alpha + str(index))
            index = index + 1
```

Here I am giving DataFrame and a list of columns which have formula in them as input. Later I am iterating over DataFrame and updating formula for each cell in that column using OpenpyXl Translator method.

This is the best solution I have figured yet.
Please let me know if there is a better way.